# Change default text editor in fedora 20 kde

Tags: fedora, kde-plasma, gedit

I have always been a fan of `Gedit` in Linux as my default text editor. How do I make it the defualt in `Fedora 20 kde`. I know that it is so in Gnome but I want the same in KDE. Is there a way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Right-click on a text file -> Preferences -> Then there is a button for the file association.

That will open a dialog where you can change the default application for this file type. Select Gedit, put it on the first position and apply the changes.

Comment: Is there a default application option from a central location?

Comment: There is something for default applications in the system settings, but not for text editors I think. Also there is "file associations" in the kde system settings, but that seems to be specific for individual file types.

Comment: I had the same problem.

Comment: Thanks stefandtw on a parallel problem.  That method works perfectly for photo files!

Comment: There actually is a central location - _kind of_. When you change preferences for `text/plain`, you'll find out it's reflected in a whole bunch of other file types as well, because they somehow derive from `text/plain`. But it's not immediately visible...